# How to "print" something to the stderr webui of an application

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 with pyspark.
from my master's web UI I can navigate to the webUI of a running application. There I can open the stderr log which presents me with information about the application. Like for example:

```
17/09/06 17:20:02 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 0 on host 1.1.1.1
17/09/06 17:20:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 11111.
17/09/06 17:20:02 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 1.1.1.1:11111
```

and so on.

now I want to output information from my application to this weblog and I seem to not really to understand how to do that. The two things I tried are:

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger()
logger.warn('This will show up as expected')
```

and

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("pyspark script logger initialized")
```

both without a result.

so how do I manage to output something on the WebUI log of an spark application?